# XSLT 1.0 insert multiple new nodes in sequence

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I need to transform an xml file from one version to another by adding new elements and their children to the older version to make it compatible with the newer version. (Version 1 --> Version 2) where version 2 has some new required elements. If there are missing elements or missing children we need to add default values. Sequence also matters here.
For example version 1:

```
<root>
  <a>
    <a1>A1</a1>
    <a2>A2</a2>
  </a>
  <b>
    <b1>B1</b1>
  </b>
</root>
```

Version 2:

```
<root>
  <a>
    <a1>A1</a1>
    <a3>A3</a3>
    <a2>A2</a2>
  </a>
  <c>
    <c1>C1</c1>
    <c2>C2</c2>
  </c>
  <d>
    <d1>D1</d1>
    <d2>D2</d2>
    <d3>D3</d3>
  </d>
  <b>
    <b1>B1</b1>
  </b>
</root>
```

I have tried a several thing but seem to run into road blocks that I can't get passed yet.  I create variables for the default values in hopes of looping through them and adding as needed.

```
<xsl:variable name="defaultA">
  <a1>aOne<a1>
  <a2>aTwo<a2>
</xsl:variable>

 .
 .
 .
<xsl:variable name="defaultC">
  <c1>cOne<c1>
  <c2>cTwo<c2>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="defaultB">
  <b1>bOne<b1>
  <b2>bTwo<b2>
</xsl:variable>


<xsl:template match="root">
 <xsl:variable name="defaults" select="document('')/*/xsl:variable[contains(@name,'default')]/*" />
 <xsl:variable name="defaultNodes" select="ext:node-set($defaults)"/>
 <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:for-each select="$defaultNodes">
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()[not(name() = name(current()))]"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This will add the nodes but it adds the namespace to the elements (which i don't want) and will keep adding elements event if they are already there.

Any help to move me in the right direction would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Se if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46186822/3016153

Comment: It gives me some ideas but not sure how to add multiple nodes when the node list could be very large.  It would seem I would have to create something like this which seems like a lot of work:                                       <xsl:apply-templates select="a"/>                         
<xsl:apply-templates select="a | b"/>                                                 <xsl:apply-templates select="a | b | c"/>                                     <xsl:apply-templates select="a | b | c | d"/>  with templates created for each combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most convenient method depends a great deal on what your content models look like, and whether any of the elements required in v2 are present but optional in v1.

From what you say, I guess that

- Every element allowed in v1 remains legal in v2 and should be retained.
- Some elements optional in v1 are required in v2; if they are present in the instance they should be retained and if they are absent, a default should be provided.
- The content model is a flat sequence of elements, with no repetitions and no subgroups.
- The sequence of elements in v1 is a subsequence of that in v2 (that is, all elements in a valid v1 instance retain their relative positions in v2).

If these guesses are wrong, you will need to make suitable adjustments in the answer (and you might consider trying to make your question clearer).

There are then several cases to consider:

- Element is required in v2 and required, optional, or absent in v1.
- Element is optional in v2 and required, optional, or absent in v1.

As an example, let's assume an element required in v1 has a name beginning with 'R' and similarly elements optional and absent in v1 have names beginning 'O' and 'A'.  Elements required and optional in v1 have names ending 'R' and 'O'.  So we have six cases, represented here by elements AO, AR, OO, OR, RO, RR. The content model for v1 is `(OO?, OR?, RO, RR)`, and the content model for v2 is `(AO?, AR, OO?, OR, RO?, RR)`.

A simple template to handle the parent element (I'll call it P) would look like this (not tested):

```
<xsl:template match="P">
  <!--* AO is optional and will never appear in v1 input.
      * So we do nothing. *-->

  <!--* AR is required and will never appear in v1 input.
      * So we inject it unconditionally. *-->
  <xsl:call-template name="default-AR"/>

  <!--* OO is optional and might appear in v1 input.
      * So we keep it if it's here. *-->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="OO"/>

  <!--* OR is required and might appear in v1 input.
      * We keep it if it's already present and supply a
      * default version if it's missing. *-->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="OR"/>
  <xsl:if test="not(OR)">
    <xsl:call-template name="default-OR"/>
  </xsl:if>

  <!--* RO is optional but will always appear in v1 input.
      * We keep it. *-->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="RO"/>

  <!--* RR is required in v1 and v2.  Just keep it. *-->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="RR"/>
</xsl:template>
```

If when you read this stylesheet six months from now you will find the logic for element OR easier to follow with an xsl:choose, use it instead of the code shown above. If you find the apply-templates followed by the if easier to follow, use it.

```
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="OR">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="OR"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:call-template name="default-OR"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
```

If the content models are not a flat sequence, the logic of your template is likely to become more complicated; in the general case it's not clear that translation from a v1 to a v2 with more element types and a possibly different structure in the content model is possible.  (Your assumption that it's possible is my main reason for guessing that both the v1 and v2 content models are flat sequences.)

Comment: Great answer.  This is where my solution ended up.  My content models are not flat so it does get a little messy.  Thanks for the response and detailed answer.